# Invalid Request when Adding Domain to a google app

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to 'Add Domain' to a google app I have.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains describes how to do this.  From the 'app engine' page, Administration -> Domain Setup -> Add Domain I put in my domain name after 'selecting an account' and supplying my password, it returns a 'Google Accounts' page with the message 'invalid request' -- not very helpful.

I'm trying to use/add a domain that I own, but google has not heard of before.  The scarce document talks about 'registering the domain' with Google apps, but doesn't say how.  Are they implying that you can only add domains that google already manages?  (I don't see how they could control my domain to get requests from it directed to their server farm.

How do I make my google app respond requests to a domain that I own?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on "Add Domain", you'll see "Domain name"on the left and "Sign up for Google Apps" on the right.

Click on "Signup for Google Apps"

You might need to create a new google apps account and connect it to your domain provider.

Comment: ?? I have a google apps account, do you have to another one for another domain??  By connect to it, do you mean something like I need to use an email address on the domain?

Comment: Yes, you can add your own domain only if it's managed by Google Apps

Answer (score 0):

**Adding other domains, by Google or others**

(I think I figured this out, with searching and help from others.)  The best documentation is: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain It seems that...

You can use three types hostnames to access a google app:

1. The .appspot.com host/domain name which is the default
2. A new host/domain name managed and hosted by google
3. A host/domain name that you got/own from some other source

The latter two cases (other than the default hostname) seem too only be available for 'paid' 'business' apps.  The process to adding a domain (case 3, for your own existing domain) requires that you create a (paid) business app and (coincidentally) have google manage email mail for the domain.

Comment: So they recently change the policy? They used to allow free hosting of 3rt party domain.

Comment: From what I saw, to verify a domain, you need to create a business app, which wasn't free.